# How can I replace an <a> tag with a <span> tag using a php if statement?

Tags: php, html, replace, tags

So I have been given a problem where with given code, I need to replace an `a` tag within an `li` tag for navigation with a `span` tag.

For example, I need to have something like this:

```
<li>
  <a href="example.com">Link text</a>
</li>
```

Look like this:

```
<li>
  <span>Link Text</span>
</li>
```

Using php to replace the `a` with `span`.

Would anyone be able to tell me what might be able to complete this? I can't use javascript and only php.

To be clear this is my understanding of what needs to be done to complete this task. If someone has a better way of doing this I'd appreciate the help. Thank you.

**This is what I currently have**

```
<ul class="page-content-nav">
  <li>
    <a class="nav-selected" href="#">Programs</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="" href="#">Programs</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

So I need the `<a>` within to be replaced with a `<span>` when it gains the class "nav-selected" which only happens when I'm on that particular page.

Hopefully this can help clarify

Comment: so given some condition, you want to change the a tag with the span tag?

Comment: Yes to an extent I believe. Maybe more of an explanation will help. I'm trying to check if when a particular link is selected in the navigation, it gains a certain class called "nav-selected" which styles/highlights that link to show its the current page you are on. So when the link is selected, I want the a tag to drop and be replaced with a span so that that particular link can no longer be clicked. I can try to explain it a little better, but hopefully this can help.

Comment: check my answer below

Comment: What have you tried so far? What exactly is going wrong? Do you get any errors? What are those errors? What have you tried to do to fix those errors? What happened when you did that? Remember to include these things when you make your question. Follow this guide to make sure your questions are of high quality: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Ok. I'll make sure to add more clarity to my questions by following that guide in the future. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly, you are trying to replace the `<a>` tag with the `<span>` tag when some condition is met. Then you explained that the condition will be when a user clicks on a link. If that is correct, you could do something like this:

```
<li>

<?php

//variable storing the class name
$className = "nav-selected";

// do all of the DOMElement operations here to determine what the class is. For this, look at the link provide in the comments
$actualClassName = "className";

if($className == $actualClassName) 
?> 
<span>Link Text</span>

<?php 
else if($someCondition == false)
?> 
<a href="example.com">Link text</a>

</li>
```

Comment: Check what I added above and let me know if I'm making it more understandable for what I need. Sorry for the constant changing, I'm just trying to make sure I correctly explain the problem I have to solve.

Comment: In that case, you need to get the class name of your <a> tag. When it equals to nav-selected, you need to replace with the <span> as I show on my answer. The tricky part is to determine the class name using PHP. To do that, you will need to use DOMElement. Take a look at this website: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php

Comment: Would there be a way of setting the class "nav-selected" to be a variable so that I can call the variable and say for instance, "when $variable is selected removes is <a> and replace it with <span>?" I appreciate the help on this. It's all very new to me so I'm still trying to get a better understanding.

Comment: I edited the answer above to make it more clear. Again, the work will be in using the DOMElement in PHP to find the class name

Comment: Ok I will try and apply what you gave me to get the solution I'm looking for. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

**Method1**

If your aim is to change the properties anchor - remove hover and clicks, you can use the below:

```
<style type="text/css">
.nav-selected{
    cursor:default; 
    pointer-events: none;
}
</style>

<ul class="page-content-nav">
  <li>
    <a class="nav-selected" href="#">Programs</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="" href="#">Programs</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Method 2**

The below not actual code, just an idea.

```
<?php

echo '<ul class="page-content-nav">';
while/for(Loop through your array or mysql)
{
    $Link = $array['link']; //eg: 'http://something.page.php'
    $Text = $array['menu_name']; //eg: programs
    $Id   = $array['id'];

    if ($Id == $current_page_id)
    {
    echo '
    <li>
        <span class="nav-selected" href="#">'.$Text.'</span>
    </li>
    ';
    }
    else
    {
    echo '
    <li>
        <a class="" href="'.$Link.'">'.$Text.'</a>
    </li>
    ';
    }

}
echo '</ul>';
?>
```

Comment: I had done foreach loops to create certain things in my current code. If I were to say for instance, "foreach time the $Id is equal to $current_page_id and if that current page contains the class nav-selected, the echo out a span as you did above? I have done the first method and was able to get the result I wanted in a simpler way. But unfortunately for this problem I need to apply using php, not css, to achieve the same affect. But all in all, that first method gives me the exact result I want, but just not in the way it needs to be done.

Comment: Is your navigation are generated dynamically using php or static navigation

Answer (score 0):

I've made a class that does just that:

```
class LiBuilder{

    public function buildListElement($text,$href=null){
        $li_inner_html = $this->buildListElementInnerHtml($text,$href);
        $li = $this->wrapInLi($li_inner_html);
        return $li;
    }

    private function buildListElementInnerHtml($text,$href){
        if($href)
            $li_inner_html = $this->buildAnchorElement($text,$href);
        else
            $li_inner_html = $this->buildSpanElement($text);
        return $li_inner_html;
    }

    private function wrapInLi($inner_html){
        return "<li>{$inner_html}</li>";
    }

    private function buildAnchorElement($href,$text){
        return "<a href=\"{$href}\">{$text}</a>";
    }

    private function buildSpanElement($text){
        return "<span>{$text}</span>";
    }

}
```

Then, you can use it like this:

```
$li_builder = new LiBuilder();
$li_1 = $li_builder->buildListElement('Here is a magic element without link');
$li_2 = $li_builder->buildListElement(
    'Another magic element but with link this time.',
    'http://www.stackoverflow.com'
);
echo $li_1, '<br />', $li_2;
```

So, just copy/paste my LiBuilder class, then require it, then call the method buildListElement.

It might be over engineered, but at least it's testable and relatively clean. Don't forget to check against XSS.